# Can I ssh to Mac using Windows Command line without using other tool like putty?

Tags: ios, windows, macos, batch-file, auto-build

I have a CI system on my Windows to build my server code.

Nowadays, I also want to autobuild my IOS project daily, but it can only build in Mac system.

So I write a shell script that can build my ios project on my Mac, and I want to remotely execute my script from Windows.

How can I write a batch file on Windows to remote access my Mac and execute my script there?
So I can make my CI system to execute that batch file everyday automatically.

Or... does anyone got other better ways to do this thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get "plink" from the PuTTY download page. Put the command(s) to kick off your Mac shell script in a file (e.g. "maccommands.txt") on your Windows computer. Then make a batch file that contains:

```
plink -l macusername -m maccommands.txt your.mac.ip.address
```

If you don't want to be prompted for a password every time, you could make a public-private keypair with an empty passphrase using PuTTYgen. Save the private key as "pc_rsa.ppk" (or whatever you want to call it). Copy the public key out of the PuTTYgen window to the clipboard, and paste it in a text editor and save it (e.g. as "pc_rsa_pub.txt").

Then transfer the file with public key over to the Mac, and add its contents to the end of ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, e.g. with `cat pc_rsa_pub.txt >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
Then add `-i pc_rsa.ppk` to the plink command above to use your private key.

(This obviously has security implications, so protect the private key file. You could also use `-pw password` but that has even greater security implications as the password would be plainly visible within your batch file.)

Comment: Thanks! I tried command: plink -l MyIP -l MyName -pw MyPassword -m test.txt, but I got a FATAL ERROR that says: Server refused to start a shell/command. I can't figured out what happened?   my test.txt just write "ls -al" as a test command

Comment: Oh! I fix it by change -s to -ssh and now I can finish what I want! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use openssh. The benefit is not having to use an alternative format for your keys.

You can install [Git for Windows](http://git-scm.com/download/win). During the installation choose the third option of being able to use the "unix" tools from the command line.

I have a small wrapper utility that loads the agent to memory in [github](http://erezak.github.io/ssh-agent-wrapper-win) (#selfplug)